# API gateway axios network Error on Mac OS

Tags: amazon-web-services, axios, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to call an API with axios from my ReactJS application (Mac). But I keep getting this error message,

**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api_url/' from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

I referred other stackoverflow answers but the error is still coming. I don't know where I made a mistake whether It is in AWS backend or Frontend. If anyone has an idea or solution please share.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Hi Arun. Did you solve your issue back in 2018? It would be useful documentation to mark my answer as "Accepted! if it did.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) being disabled by default.

Your React app comes from a different domain (e.g https://localhost:3000) and therefore cannot call remote servers by default (e.g 'https://api_url/).

See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) and [enable-cors](https://enable-cors.org) for great explanations.

This must be enabled explicitly.

AWS API Gateway will let you do this from the UI.

- Select your API in the UI
- In the actions dropdown choose "Enable CORS"
- Follow the forms to enable and you should be good to go!